# SAPUI5:Chart: Changing the color of a bar

Tags: sapui5

We would like to change the color of a particular bar in the chart. Can someone share a code snippet to achieve the same? If we use color-pallete aggregation then color change is getting reflected to all the bars.

We are using makit library, please note that we had tried the same with viz library also.

Snippet from XML view:

```
<ma:Chart id="idChart1" height="50%" width="100%" type="Column"
  rows="{/}" showRangeSelector="true"
  showTableView="false" showTotalValue="false">


  <ma:category>
  <ma:Category column="type" displayName="Product" />
  </ma:category>


  <ma:values>
  <ma:Value expression="tickets" displayName="Gross Value"
  format="number" />
  </ma:values>
  <ma:columns>
  <ma:Column name="type" value="{BillCycle}" />
  <ma:Column name="tickets" value="{Volume}" type="number" />
  </ma:columns>`enter code here`


  </ma:Chart>
```

Regards,
DR